# Why does a measurement on one qubit force another one into a given state in Simon's algorithm?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

This comes from trying to understand the "Simon's algorithm".

So we have a set of $2^n$ kets $|x_i >$ one each for $i \in \{0,1\}^n$. Each $x_j \in \{0,1\}^n$. And we have the further constraint that $x_i = x_j$ iff $i = j + s (mod\text{ }2) = j \oplus s$ (bitwise addition modulo $2$) for a certain $s \in \{0,1\}^n$. (so every $|x_k>$ is guaranteed to have a second copy)

Now one has this state given as $\psi_a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{i \in \{0,1\}^n} |i>|x_i> $ So this is a state of some 2 qubit system.

- Given this I want to understnd why a measurement on the second qubit would necessarily collapse this to the state, $\psi_b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( |j> + |j \oplus s>)|x_j>$ for some $j \in \{0,1\}^n$ ?

---

Is there a derivation of this? Like why is a measurement output on the second qubit forcing a particular state for the first qubit?

I would have thought that we can only say that the state $\psi_b$ will be obtained with a probability of $(\bar{\psi_b} \psi_a)^2$. And this probability is equal to $(\frac{ 2}{ \sqrt{2^{n+1} }})^2 = 1/2^{n-1}$.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The reason a measurement outcome on the second qubit forces a particular state for the first qubit is that the two qubits are entangled.

You are correct about the probability of measuring state $\psi_b$, but the issue is that $\psi_b$ is under-determined, since $j$ can take any value in $\{0,1\}^n$. So when you perform the measurement on the second qubit, every outcome looks like $\psi_b$, simply with different values of $j$. Any specific value of $j$ has some probability less than 1, but here we are not talking about a specific value of $j$, we are talking about any value of $j$.

As an example, consider the bell state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle|0\rangle+|1\rangle|1\rangle)$. I can say that if I measure the second qubit (in the computational basis) then I am certain to get a state of the form $|j\rangle |j\rangle$. Of course the state $|0\rangle|0\rangle$ has probability 1/2, but that is irrelevant. This is identical to your situation.

Comment: Seems my question isn't clear. This particular $\psi_b$ in my question is *not* the only state in the Hilbert space of these two qubits. If I understand the notation correctly then the first qubit can be in any of the $|i>$ states of which there are $2^n$ of them and the second qubit can be in any of the $|x_i>$ states of which there are $2^n$ of them. So there are $2^{2n}$ states available in this Hilbert space of these 2 qubits. Then why do we think that states of only this $\psi_b$ type will be measured?

Comment: Clarification : I mean that the observation could have collapsed it to may be any of the vectors in this $2^{2n}$ dimensional vector space. But then why are these $\psi_b$s special? Is this observation by an operator such that $\psi_b$s are its eigenstates? Then that would make sense.

Comment: Certainly there are vectors in the Hilbert space that it would be impossible to observe given $\psi_a$. Take again the bell state example, we should never expect to measure the state $|0\rangle|1\rangle$. Additionally, it is assumed that the measurement on the second register is made in the computational basis, so we should not expect to find the second register in a superposition of computational basis states (although that constraint need not be applied to the first register, since only the second register is being measured)

Comment: Indeed, given that we are measuring $\psi_a$ in the computational basis, the only possible outcome is $\psi_b$. This is most readily observed by noting that $\psi_a$ can be expressed as a superposition of exclusively states of the form $\psi_b$.

Comment: (1) So is this measurement  measuring a certain observable/(Hermitian operator) whose eigenstates are theses $\psi_b$s? Then that makes perfect sense that the observation is one of these $\psi_b$s. (to give an alaogy given a spin 1/2 if one measures its spin in the x direction then its no surprise that one would get either the $|1/2,(1/2)_x>$ or $|1/2,(-1/2)_x>$ state)  (2) Can you explain what is a "computational basis"? What do you mean by "measurement on the second register is made in the computational basis" ?

Comment: Also These $\psi_b$s do NOT seem to have this property that they are able to span the entire Hilbert space. They are not a basis. The probabilities don't add up either $\sum_b ( \bar{\psi_b} \psi_a )^2 = 1/2$ Then it becomes more unclear as to why you think something which is not of the $\psi_b$ will not be observed.

Comment: CLARIFICATION : But the probabilities don't add up rightly either $\sum_b ( \bar{\psi_b} \psi_a )^2 = 2$. Wonder is the interpretation of the fact that the probabilites over all these possibilities seem to add up to $2$!

Comment: (1) The eigenstates of the observable are not the $\psi_b$s, they are the computational basis states of the second register ((2) the computational basis is the set $\{|\{0,1\} \rangle\}$. The reason you only get $\psi_b$ is because of the specific structure of $\psi_a$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25765/discussion-between-joel-klassen-and-user6818).

Comment: That $\psi_a$ is a linear combination of the $\psi_b$s can't be the reason why the wave-function collapses into only the $\psi_b$ states! One could have as well chosen a different basis to expand the $\psi_a$s in and gotten a different result!

Comment: I think the issue is as to what do you mean by "measuring in the computational basis". What is this? This is what is forcing the collapse into the $\psi_b$ states. This would make sense only if the measurement is by an operator for whom the $\psi_b$ are the eigenstaes.

Comment: I have opened a chat for us to continue this conversation, as this is becoming an extended discussion. Please see my above post.